# Setting NSWindow position in current screen

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, nswindowcontroller, nspoint

I am newbie in objective-c.I have created a main window which I want to display in the right bottom of the current screen. I tried the following code

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    NSPoint pos;

    pos.x = [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame].origin.x + [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame].size.width - [mywindow frame].size.width ;

    pos.y = [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame].origin.y + [[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame].size.height - [mywindow frame].size.height;

    [mywindow setFrameTopLeftPoint:pos];

}
```

what is wrong with in it? How to resolve it?

Comment: @student: Nope,It is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
NSPoint pos; 
pos.x = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.width - [mywindow frame].size.width ;

pos.y = 0.0f;

[self.window setFrame:CGRectMake(pos.x, pos.y, [mywindow frame].size.width , [mywindow frame].size.height) display:YES];
```

Because  [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].origin.x will always be 0. 
And in case of mac screen starts from bottom.

Comment: This actually isn't true, `mainScreen` is the screen that has the mainWindow; which may or may not be the screen that has an x origin of 0. The origin screen (the one that contains 0,0, is `[[NSScreen screens] firstObject]`