# Swift 3/macOS: Open window on certain screen

Tags: swift, macos, window, screen

Beginner question:

I am working on a macOS App with current Xcode 8.3.3 and Swift3. I am using MASShortcut to open a window by a shortcut that has been hidden by startup.

I use the following code on the shortcut event:

```
NSApplication.shared().windows.last!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
NSApplication.shared().activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```

For multiple monitor setups (I have two external displays attached to my MacBook), I want to specify the screen where the window pops up. I know there is NSScreen.screens() that gives back all available screens. But how do I use it for letting my window pop up on screen 1/2/3?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: Solved with the answer of @michael-doltermann:

I can iterate over NSScreen.screens() and access for example the midX/midY coords to create a NSPoint instance to replace my window.

```
var pos = NSPoint()
pos.x = NSScreen.screens()![myIndex].visibleFrame.midX)
pos.y = NSScreen.screens()![myIndex].visibleFrame.midY)
self.window?.setFrameOrigin(pos)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each screen from `NSScreen.screens()` has a `visibleFrame` property that tells you the global frame rectangle.

You can then set your window origin to fit inside the frame rect coordinates of whatever screen you want. Objective-C answers can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195977/how-to-change-the-nsscreen-a-nswindow-appears-on) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512553/setting-nswindow-position-in-current-screen).

This does mean you have to write some code to specify the preferred window. In my own app, I take the global frame rectangles for each screen and then scale them way down into a NSView to display something that looks like the Monitors pane from System Preferences:

[image: Set Video Preferences]

Comment: Thank you!

I got it.
I can iterate over NSScreen.screens() and access for example the midX/midY coords to create a NSPoint instance to replace my window.

    var pos = NSPoint()
    pos.x = NSScreen.screens()![myIndex].visibleFrame.midX)
    pos.y = NSScreen.screens()![myIndex].visibleFrame.midY)
    self.window?.setFrameOrigin(pos)